# How to use 'when' conditional with Systemd Unit configs

Tags: linux, docker, systemd, coreos

How can I use a 'when' or 'if' conditional statement with systemd Units on CoreOS?

For example: I want to mount a directory only if a variable is set to True (say `A == "True"`)

So like:

```
- name: var-lib-docker.mount
  contents: |
    [Unit]
    Description=Mount ephemeral to /var/lib/docker
    [Mount]
     if (A == "true") # This part I'm not sure where and how to put.
       What=/dev/xvd1
       Where=/var/lib/docker
       Type=ext4
```

Comment: I've not yet fiddled much with units ... do they not understand common tests like 
[ "$A" = "TRUE" ] && echo "do this"

Comment: Could you link to the CoreOS docs you are following? I haven't seen this YAML format used for systemd configuration before.

Comment: @ankit What are you using to create this file? Is it ansible?

Comment: Eh. "When" conditionals are an ansible construct, not a systemd construct.

Comment: @louigi600, those "common tests" are snippets of shell script. systemd units are not interpreted by a shell.

Comment: @Matt/@MarkStosberg: This is not Ansible, this is in a systemd Unit conf wherein I'm using dropins. Ref: https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/mounting-storage.html

Comment: @ankittyagi Did you got any solution to this ? i am also facing a similar issue .

Comment: @zappy, if you could provide a comment describing why my answer doesn't work for you, that would help me extend it to show an option that _might_ work. (There _are_ options -- systemd generators, for example -- but none of them work exactly like what the OP asked for).

Answer (score 1):

Merely creating a unit does not not describe when and under what circumstances that unit is activated; that activation is what you care about here -- so a solution could be as simple as having other code only tell systemd to start the mount unit at hand if you want it to be up.

If you want the unit to perform its own conditional evaluation at startup, however, see [`man systemd.unit`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) for various flags for the purpose. For example:

```
[Unit]
ConditionPathExists=/etc/mount-docker
```

would cause the filesystem to only be mounted if `/etc/mount-docker` exists. Similarly, you could decide whether to enable the unit for the mount point from Ansible based on logic running at that layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something conditional that can't be done with `systemd` on CoreOS, their `cloud-config` tool has a [write_file](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/cloud-config.html) directive. Using that, you could write a bash script to disk that contains the conditional logic you want. Then you could create a `systemd` service which starts that bash script. The bash script could in turn make other calls to `systemctl start ...` to start other `systemd` services or mounts.